# Lyrics of Counting Stars

Tags: lyrics

There are many versions of the lyrics of the Song Counting Stars by One Republic at this part

> Take that money
>
> Watch it burn
>
> Sing in the river / Sink in the river
>
> The lessons I learned / I've learned / are learned

What's the right lyrics here?

Comment: If I recall, the lyrics in the version I know vary a bit as the song goes on anyway. And the words are not always distinct.  From a point of view of "making sense", 'Sink in the river/the lessons I've learned" make most sense in keeping with the feeling expressed in 'Take that money/watch it burn'

Comment: We will never know. I have the album but the lyrics aren't in it.

Comment: @Manto, please accept the answer if it's ok for you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [shazam](http://www.shazam.com/track/83147960/counting-stars) and [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tmz4cqkxfvabslm5q4e6vmme6yi?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics) the lyrics are:

```
Take that money

Watch it burn

Sink in the river

The lessons I've learned
```